# Vba write combobox list to sheet

Tags: vba

Hi is there a way to write the list that is populated in a combobox to a sheet?
the reason I ask is I have a combobox where the user can remove items from it but because I have to make some calculations with the items that is left I need to write the remaining items back to a sheet. I haven't found what I'm looking for because all post its about listbox and when they are selected items.

The only thing I could come up with but which is not working is this:

```
Set StableTour = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stableford")
```

For i = 0 To ComboBox1.ListCount - 1
   StableTour.Range("I" & i + 2) = ComboBox1.List(i)
   Next

Comment: ComboBox1.List returns 2D array that you can use directly without writing to sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this tutorial here:
http://www.contextures.com/Excel-VBA-ComboBox-Lists.html

You should be using:

```
StableTour.Range("I" & i +2) = ComboBox1.List(i, 1)
```

If this doesn't fix it, please include what error you are getting.